# Insert performance with Cassandra

Tags: python, multithreading, insert, cassandra

sorry for my English in advance.

I am a beginner with Cassandra and his data model. I am trying to insert one million rows in a cassandra database in local on one node. Each row has 10 columns and I insert those only in one column family.

With one thread, that operation took around 3 min. But I would like do the same operation with 2 millions rows, and keeping a good time. Then I tried with 2 threads to insert 2 millions rows, expecting a similar result around 3-4min. bUT i gor a result like 7min...twice the first result. As I check on differents forums, multithreading is recommended to improve performance.
That is why I am asking that question : is it useful to use multithreading to insert data in local node (client and server are in the same computer), in only one column family?

Some informations :
 - I use pycassa
 - I have separated commitlog repertory and data repertory on differents disks
 - I use batch insert for each thread
 - Consistency Level : ONE
 - Replicator factor : 1

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a similar problem and I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* you're hitting the python GIL but more likely you're doing something wrong.

For instance, putting 2M rows in a single batch would be Doing It Wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not putting 2M rows in a single batch. Each thread connects on database, and insert 1M rows with a batch configured with a queue_size of 1000.

Comment: You should start with contrib/stress because then you know the load-generation part isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running multiple clients in multiple processes, NOT threads.

Then experiment with different insert sizes.

1M inserts in 3 mins is about 5500 inserts/sec, which is pretty good for a single local client. On a multi-core machine you should be able to get several times this amount provided that you use multiple clients, probably inserting small batches of rows, or individual rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am just change my program with multiple processes (one fork) but no improvement. I am thinking that would be my program is too complex : it reads on csv file, insert data in batchs, then send those to database. I used the time command and user time was around 2min... For a single local client (with 4cores), it is probably to much to schedule my program and the database in a same time

Answer (score 0):

You might consider Redis.  Its single-node throughput is supposed to be faster.  It's different from Cassandra though, so whether or not it's an appropriate option would depend on your use case.

Comment: Yes I heard about Redis, but it is not a good match for my data model, unfortunatly...

Answer (score 0):

The time taken doubled because you inserted twice as much data. Is it possible that you are I/O bound?